# How to load a CSS into a JavaScript variable in Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack-5, postcss-loader

## I have

*style.css*

```
section {
    display: flex;
    background: url('./bg.svg');
}
```

*script.mjs*

```
import css from './style.css'
console.log(css)
```

*webpack.config.mjs*

```
import path from 'path'
import url from 'url';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

const __dirname = path.dirname(url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

export default {
  mode: 'production',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'script.mjs'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: `[name].js`,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
        type: 'asset/inline',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        type: 'asset/source',
        use: [
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                autoprefixer,
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "~10.2.5",
    "css-loader": "~5.2.4",
    "postcss-loader": "~5.2.0",
    "webpack": "~5.36.2",
    "webpack-cli": "~4.6.0"
  }
}
```

## Expected console.log output

```
display: -webkit-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,...');
```

## Actual result

I got the build error when the postcss-loader is present:

```
PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema"
```

And I got the wrong output in console.log when there is no postcss-loader in webpack.config.mjs:

```
// Imports
import ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ from "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js";
import ___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___ from "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js";
import ___CSS_LOADER_URL_IMPORT_0___ from "./bg.svg";
var ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___ = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(function(i){return i[1]});
var ___CSS_LOADER_URL_REPLACEMENT_0___ = ___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___(___CSS_LOADER_URL_IMPORT_0___);
// Module
___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.push([module.id, "section {\n\tdisplay: flex;\n\tbackground: url(" + ___CSS_LOADER_URL_REPLACEMENT_0___ + ");\n}", ""]);
// Exports
export default ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___;
```

Comment: Can you please try `loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [autoprefixer]
                            }
                        },` instead of `loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                autoprefixer,
              ],
            },` in your webpack.config.mjs and if it still does not work out then please try to replace the `[ autoprefixer ],` like so `[],` & then `rm -f package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: @Subha, yep, it fixed the "PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema" error. Thanks! But console.log still outputs a "dirty" css.

Comment: glad that it worked out. Can you please share again what the console is logging exactly after the fix.

Comment: @Subha, output is similar to the output in question: ```// Imports
import ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___ from "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js";
import ___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___ from "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/getUrl.js";
import ___CSS_LOADER_URL_IMPORT_0___ from "./bg.svg";
var ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___ = ___CSS_LOADER_API_IMPORT___(function(i){return i[1]});
var ___CSS_LOADER_URL_REPLACEMENT_0___ = ___CSS_LOADER_GET_URL_IMPORT___(___CSS_LOADER_URL_IMPORT_0___);
// Module
___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.push([module.id, "section {\n\tdisplay: flex;\n\tbackg ...```

Comment: Did some troubleshooting and posted the answer. Please check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these fixes for the two separate issues

> 1. PostCSS Loader not initializing:

```
  //....{
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [
              autoprefixer,
            ],
          },
        },
      }, //....
```

> 2. console is not logging expected out:
>    Currently, the CSS file is loading but is not converted to a string and hence you see garbage in your console. You need [systemjs/text plugin](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text) to load the text from the CSS file as a string.

**At first do the following in your terminal**

```
//install Systemjs
npm install systemjs
//install jspm
npm install jspm@0.16x -g
// change over to your project directory
cd my-project
//intall jspm into your project
npm install jspm@0.16x --save-dev
//initialise jspm
jspm init
//install text plugin
jspm install text
```

**Then in your script.mjs**

```
import './style.css!';
// Now, you can retrieve the contents of the file using the text plugin:
import css from './style.css!text';
console.log(css);
```

Please note: There are other ways of installing systemjs/text plugin as well. Please refer [systemjs/text](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text) and [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) for more installation info.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it later and comment about the result.

Comment: @mihail-haritonov welcome. If it works would be great if you could just accept my answer then I will know it worked. Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working (I got "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'text' in '/home/m/projects/upwork/webpack-test'") and I switched to rollup with config ```plugins: [postcss({plugins: [cssurl({url: 'inline'})]})```